# Jmeter - How to encode HTTP Sampler response to UTF-8

Tags: httprequest, jmeter-3.2

I'm using HTTP Sampler in Jmeter 3.2 and get result in a way:

> Pączek

But when I extract response using JSR223 PostProcessor with prev.getResponseDataAsString() I get in Debug:

> P�czek

I already added line:

> sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8

In jmeter.properties

And:

> file.encoding=UTF-8

In system.properties

And also added Content Encoding : UTF-8 in HTTP Sampler and HTTP Header with Content-Type paramter set to application/json; charset=utf-8 and added line:

> prev.setDataEncoding("UTF-8");

In Post Processor
But nevertheless the results is the same. Maybe there is some other way to configure that?

Comment: Try add header to request: `Content-Type` value `text/plain; charset=utf-8`